# Is there an easy way to find the cohomology ring of the complex projective plane?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, projective-space

I am trying to find the cohomology ring of $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2$. But I don't know how. We know from the CW structure of $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2$ that the cohomology groups  must be $\mathbb{Z}$ in dimensions 0,2 and 4 and 0 otherwise.So the only non obvious cup product we need to compute is the generator of the second cohomology group with it self. Is there any efficient way to do that.Or at least a way to show that it wont result to 0?

Thanks

Comment: What did you find out when you looked this up in textbooks?

Comment: I believe this is what Schubert calculus is for, though perhaps that's too general for your requirements.

Comment: While the proof is in most textbooks, admittedly it is quite technical and some intuition based on the simple CW structure would be nice, so I don't see why to downvote.

Comment: What definitions do you know for cohomology, and what tools do you have? The result is an immediate consequence of Poincare duality, easy using the relation between cup product and transverse intersections of submanifolds and a doable computation in de Rham cohomology. On the other hand, if I am required to do this directly from the definition of cup product in simplicial cohomology, it will be painful.

Comment: I have not yet been introduced to the poincare duallity. Basically the only tools I know are just the cellular cohomology. I know there are some technical proofs in textbooks.However I was hoping(for the simple case n=2)that there is a simple intuitive way to figure out the cup product  just by considering the CW structure  or at least to show that is nonzero

Answer (score 5):

I know a way using differential forms. Since $\mathbb{CP}^2$ is a manifold, most of the cohomologies of it are canonically isomorphic to each other. Because you mentioned its CW structure, I assume you are talking about the singular cohomology. You already know that,

$H^n_{\Delta}(\mathbb{CP}^2)$ =
  \begin{cases}
    \mathbb{Z}       & \quad \text{if } n =0, 2, 4\\
    0  & \quad \text{otherwise.}\\
  \end{cases}

Tensor it with $\mathbb{R}$, by the universal coefficient theorem you get

$H^n_{\Delta}(\mathbb{CP}^2;\mathbb{R})$ =
  \begin{cases}
    \mathbb{R}       & \quad \text{if } n =0, 2, 4\\
    0  & \quad \text{otherwise.}\\
  \end{cases}
(This is compatible with the product structure.)
By the de Rham theorem, you know $H^\ast_{\Delta}(\mathbb{CP}^2,\mathbb{R}) \cong H^\ast_{dR}(\mathbb{CP}^2)$ as $\mathbb{R}$-algebra where the multiplication on the left hand side is the cup product $\cup$ and that of the right hand side is the wedge product $\wedge$.

There is a Fubini-study form on $\mathbb{CP}^2$ which is defined by
$$ \omega_{FS} = i \partial \bar{\partial} log (|u_0|^2+|u_1|^2+1)$$
where $[u_0:u_1:1] = [z_0:z_1:z_2]$ is the local coordinate.

First $\omega_{FS}$ is a closed form because $\partial \bar{\partial} f(|z|^2) = d \bar{\partial} f(|z|^2)$ for $f \in C^\infty (\mathbb{R})$. So $[\omega_{FS}] \in H^2_{dR}(\mathbb{CP}^2)$. If we can show that $ [\omega_{FS}] \wedge [\omega_{FS}] \neq 0$ in $H^2_{dR}(\mathbb{CP}^2)$, then we know the $\mathbb{R}$-algebra structure is non-trivail. We can calculate that,

\begin{align*}
 \omega_{FS}^2 &=\frac{-1}{(|u_0|^2+|u_1|^2+1)^3} du_0 \wedge d\bar{u_0} \wedge du_1 \wedge d\bar{u_1} \\
&=\frac{4}{(x_0^2+y_0^2+x_1^2+y_1^2+1)^3} dx_0 \wedge dy_0 \wedge dx_1 \wedge dy_1.
\end{align*}

This shows $\int_{\mathbb{CP}^2} \omega_{FS}^2 \neq 0 $ and so $[\omega_{FS}^2] \neq 0$ by the Poincare duality.